# React native Bottom Tab not showing

Tags: react-native, expo

BottomTab is not working on my app and it isn't showing any error:
App JS
[image: App JS]

tabs JS
[image: tabs JS]

Comment: do you have any github repository for the code? So, that I can test on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js file, the `navigator` has a props: `initialRouteName={'Home'}`

This means `navigator` will load `Stack.Screen` with `name="Home"`, in this case your app is showing the **Home component** for the main screen but not the **Tabs component** for main screen.

My suggestion: change `initialRouteName={'Home'}` to `initialRouteName={'Tabs'}` in line 18 of `App.js` file